# Control Access to Microsoft Azure Account

Tags: azure, access-control, user-management, role-based-access-control

Our company has a Microsoft Azure account (Pay-As-You-Go).

We had a programmer that developed our web app. We gave him full access to our Azure account. So, he had access to everything.

We intend to hire another developer to make modifications to the web app, so he'll need access to the App Services and SQL Databases. Our intention is to just allow him access to those features.

We did our research and came across the documentation, Resources, roles, and access control in Application Insights. We followed it step by step, but there's an issue. [Doc LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-resources-roles-access-control)

We tested the procedure by adding one of our IT staff's Microsoft account (personal Outlook.com account) and assigning him the Contributor role, and sent him an invite. He's not seeing the invite. We did the same for another staff, but it's the same problem.

Can we get some assistance please?

Comment: Please use your azure account to login office365, and check your sent items. does that mail send successfully?

Comment: Have you tried login with the outlook account after you add it? There will be no invite sent to the user now, I believe the screenshot in the link you provided is out of date. Please try logging with the outlook account directly

Comment: The user logged in and checked their email at outlook.com and there's no invitation. They logged in at azure with same account and still no invitation.
Remember it's their personal email account as the document in the link above suggests was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working earlier .I tried with one gmail id. Now it is working perfectly fine and I am able to receive the invitation email.

To send invitation, you need to go to active  directory. Add user's email as a guest under add user option (Add guest user).

Comment: So invitation went through now, but "There are no applications available. Please contact your admin for more information."

Comment: This invitation is to add user in Azure AD.Once user is added into AD (after acceptance) you can provide access your application by adding  user into access /role

Comment: Will try that later today

Comment: Tried it and it worked. 

I've been doing that, but not in that order.

Thank you!